# Analytical function issue

Tags: teradata

I am working on a history handling issue. I am writing a query to update the wrong entries for the start_date. The data in the table is as below:

```
Subs_is subs_cd     number  start_dt    end_dt
ABC 100 7854    10/8/2015   3/9/2015
ABC 100 58742   10/9/2015   20/09/2015
ABC 100 1278    23/09/2015  30/09/2015
ABC 100 4785    15/10/2015  25/10/2015
```

I want the start_date to be previous row end_date when the number changes.

can anyone please help me with this.

regards,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a simple `LAG` (which is not implemented in Teradata, but easy to rewrite):

```
-- lag(start_date) -- not implemented
-- over (partition by Subs_is, subs_cd 
--       order by start_dt

-- previous row's value
max(start_dt)
over (partition by Subs_is, subs_cd 
      order by start_dt
      rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
```